# AirDrop after moving Download folder

Tags: icloud, airdrop

I have moved my `Downloads` folder to a subfolder of `Documents`, since I want it to also sync using `iCloud Drive` with `Desktop & Documents Folders` sync active.

I did this by removing the `~/Downloads` folder and linking it to `~/Documents/Downloads` with `ln -s`.

This works perfectly for downloads I do with i.e. Safari and other apps. The only issue I have is when using `AirDrop`. Every time I AirDrop to my Mac, I can see the progress bar, the folder hops, and it receives the file. It even gives me the audio-acknowledgement that the transfer is complete, but it does not appear in my Download folder. I have searched my hard drive, and the file is no where to be found.

Is there a work-around for this? Can I specify where AirDrop should place my files?

Thanks for any input/tips

Comment: don't you have a notification on the upper right corner of the screen when the file is sent ?